# min() arg is an empty sequence with error index

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm troubled, I have the sequent suggestion!

```
lista_yi_da_attiv.append (1+lista_ratio.index(min(x for in lista_ratio if x is not 0)
```

returns a sequent

> ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Answer (score 4):

In your case, `min(x for in lista_ratio if x is not 0)` might equals to `min([])` (the argument is an empty sequence) that raises `ValueError`

```
>>> min([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

---

**Specify a default value for [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) to avoid such exceptions caused by an empty sequence**. For instance,

```
min(list or [0]) # default vaule is 0
```

Python3.4 adds a default keyword argument to [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min). For instance,

```
>>> min([], default=0)
0
```

Comment: Best solution, instead of using Try Except we can follow this.

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
lista_yi_da_attiv.append(1+lista_ratio.index(min([x for x in lista_ratio if x != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

When your `x=0` you don't have an index and can't add.