# MIN function in python - why am i getting this error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I'm getting the error: `min() argument is an empty sequence`.

I'm trying to get the word with the minimum length value from the C list.

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        c=[]
        z=0

        for i in range(1,len(strs)):
            for j in strs[i]:

                for x in strs[0]:
                    if strs[i][0] != strs[0][0]:
                        return ""
                    if j == x:
                        z+=1

            c.append(strs[0][0:z])
            z=0

        return min(c,key=len)
```

Comment: You'll get that error when the list you created, `c`, is empty.

Comment: Because. in some cases you are returning from the function prematurely! So your return value in that case becomes "", or an empty string as per your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [min() arg is an empty sequence with error index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346009/min-arg-is-an-empty-sequence-with-error-index) / [min() arg empty sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557802/min-arg-empty-sequence)

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. i was trying to submit this code to leetcode site but it seems like they inputed an empty list for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do but this might help:

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: [str]) -> str:
c = []
z = 0

for i in range(1, len(strs)):
    for j in strs[i]:

        for x in strs[0]:
            if strs[i][0] != strs[0][0]:
                # return ""
                print("")
            if j == x:
                z += 1

    c.append(strs[0][0:z])
    z = 0
return min(c, key=len)


a = longestCommonPrefix(['f', 'fo', 'foo'], ['foob', 'fooba', 'foobar'])
print(a)
```